# regex to parse fully qualified Java names in stacktraces

Tags: java, regex, stack-trace

I wrote this regular expression `(at)(\\s)(\\w.+)(\\(\\w.+)(\\))` for the following string:

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method.java:585)
```

but it did not work. Could you please help me to rewrite the correct one.

Comment: How did it not work? Your question is not well formulated

Comment: java classes can have almost any character in their name (even if it is bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick ([demo](http://fiddle.re/dbp66)):

```
at (.*)\.(.*)\(([^:]*):?([\d]*)\)
```

will return package.class in group 1, method in group 2, filename in group 3 and eventual line number in group 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the periods like this `\.`.  Also `\w` matches a single word character, not a whole word.  Try something like this:

```
at\s(\w+\.)+\(\w+\.\w+:\d+\)
```

Comment: If escaping characters is the problem, then you should use `\\` instead of `\\` in order to escape the `\` character.

Comment: I have a file that has many information about a bug. I want to check if the this bug has a stack trace which has the pattern ( at xxx.xxx.xx). I try to write a regular expression to find the match string in the file which could be like this :  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method.java:585)